# Deleting text from p:textEditor using backspace-key

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to implement a sort of post-it function that users can use to make notes. I implemented this by opening p:textEditor in a dialog with "Save" and "Cancel" buttons at the bottom. This mostly works fine, the only problem is that I can't delete text in the textEditor using the backspace-key. Deleting using the del-key works fine.

Here is my code:

The commandButton that opens the dialog containing the textEditor:

```
<p:commandButton value="openPostit" widgetVar="openPostit"
                         onsuccess="PF('frmPostit').show();"
/>
```

The dialog:

```
<h:form id="frmPostit">
            <p:dialog id="dlgPostit" widgetVar="dlPostit"
                      dynamic="false" modal="false"
                      fitViewport="false" resizable="true"
                      closable="true"
                      onHide="$('#frmPostit\\:quit').click();">
                <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('dlgPostit').hide();" />
                <p:outputPanel>
                        <p:textEditor id="textPostit" widgetVar="textPostit"
                                      value="#{backingbean.text}"
                                      style="vertical-align: top; height: 450px">
                        </p:textEditor>

                    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px" >
                        <p:commandButton value="Save"
                                         actionListener="#{backingbean.saveText()}"
                                         accesskey="s"
                                         process="@form"
                                         icon="fa fa-check-square-o"
                                         oncomplete="PF('dlgPostit').hide();}"
                                         />

                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" id="quit"
                                     icon="fa fa-close"
                                     process="@this" resetValues="true"
                                     immediate="true"
                                     accesskey="a"
                                     oncomplete="PF('dlgPostit').hide();" />
                    </div>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

Any idea why the backspace-key won't delete the text in the textEditor?

**EDIT**: Additional information I found that may be interesting: I can delete linebreaks using the backspace-key (but not text)

Comment: Does it work without `p:hotkey`?

Comment: @JasperdeVries No, removing the hotkey has no effect

Comment: What PF version are you using?

Comment: @ivasanpag 6.2.17